# Load flex module on new browser tab

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I need to know if there's a way to load a Flex module on new browser tab. I wonder something like the settings interface of Dropbox...

I tried to use URLRequest to call the flex module, but no success. Any ideas?

[]'s

Comment: how did you try to use URLRequest? What do you mean by no success - error message? nothing happened? The more detail you can provide (such as showing your code), the better the answers you will receive.

Comment: ok, let's suppose that my Flex module is in the same directory as the application.. so, i should in first place, load the module with Module loader: loader.loadModule('myModule.swf') and after that, open a new tab with urlRequest, poiting to 'myModule.swf' either. But, doesn't work.. nothing happens.

Comment: Modules can only be loaded into existing swfs - browser tabs are separate entities - you dont have websites split over browser tabs do you.